# golang icmp ping issue using goroutines - getting duplicates

Tags: go, goroutine, icmp

Would love some help on this ... I'm having difficulty using icmp ping with goroutines. My goal is to write code that will ping blocks of addresses eg 10.1.0.0/22, 10.1.4.0/22 etc in the quickest possible time.

The ping part seems to work fine, but the moment I introduce a goroutine for sending icmp packets I end up with duplicate responses - it seems like the last address in the slice I am iterating through is duplicated in the goroutine and none of the other addresses are used/displayed.

I am using a slice of 20 or so ip's for simplicity (not doing the address block piece yet). It seems the last ip in the list is the one the goroutine is acting on along with the sequence number. In my output I should see a list of each ip with a unique sequence number and echoRequest ID. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "golang.org/x/net/icmp"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
    "sync"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func sendPingRequest(targetIP net.IP, sequence int, conn *icmp.PacketConn) error {
    message := icmp.Message{
            Type: ipv4.ICMPTypeEcho,
            Code: 0,
            Body: &icmp.Echo{
                ID:   rand.Intn(65000), // os.Getpid() & 0xffff,
                Seq:  sequence,
                Data: []byte("HELLO-RPC"),
            },
    }

    messageBytes, err := message.Marshal(nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = conn.WriteTo(messageBytes, &net.IPAddr{IP: targetIP})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}


var ips = []string{"192.168.1.1", "203.219.106.90", "23.206.224.65", "151.101.30.133", "6.6.6.6", "203.221.3.18", "23.40.165.66", "151.101.31.5", "143.143.143.143", "8.8.8.8", "23.219.61.138", "157.240.8.35", "104.94.145.204", "1.2.3.4", "160.34.1.130", "23.32.5.57", "142.250.204.17", "192.185.225.146", "7.7.7.7", "104.19.237.4", "18.67.93.50", "45.60.126.46", "184.84.252.163", "18.67.111.128"}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    timeout := 400 * time.Millisecond
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    conn, err := icmp.ListenPacket("ip4:icmp", "0.0.0.0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening for ICMP packets:", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    replyChannel := make(chan *icmp.Message, len(ips))

    go func() {
        for {
            message := make([]byte, 1500)
            _, _, err := conn.ReadFrom(message)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error reading ICMP packet:", err)
                continue
            }

            receivedMessage, err := icmp.ParseMessage(ipv4.ICMPTypeEcho.Protocol(), message)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error parsing ICMP packet:", err)
                continue
            }

            replyChannel <- receivedMessage
        }
    }()

    wg.Add(len(ips))
    for idx, ip := range ips {
        targetIP := net.ParseIP(ip)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            err := sendPingRequest(targetIP, idx, conn)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error sending ICMP packet:", err)
                // continue
            }

            select {
            case <-time.After(timeout):
                fmt.Printf("No response from %s\n", ip)
            case reply := <-replyChannel:
                echoReply, _ := reply.Body.(*icmp.Echo)
                fmt.Printf("Received reply from %s ...  ", ip)
                fmt.Printf("reply id: %v, seq: %v\n", echoReply.ID, echoReply.Seq)
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("\nelapsed time %v\n", time.Since(start))
}
```

the output is as follows (NB the ip & seq are all based on the last item in the slice. Also there are a few non-existent ip's so some addresses dont respond - which is correct):-
sh-3.2# go run icmp.go
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 59682, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 22751, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 42942, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 37531, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 24029, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 39323, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 31617, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 38973, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 14149, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 43518, seq: 23
reply id: 43433, seq: 23 Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 13755, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 5795, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 16212, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 28927, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 15595, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 50925, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 35796, seq: 23
Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 23039, seq: 23
No response from 18.67.111.128
No response from 18.67.111.128
No response from 18.67.111.128
No response from 18.67.111.128
No response from 18.67.111.128

elapsed time 407.883819ms
Error reading ICMP packet: read ip 0.0.0.0: raw-read ip4 0.0.0.0: use of closed network connection
Error reading ICMP packet: read ip 0.0.0.0: raw-read ip4 0.0.0.0: use of closed network connection
Error reading ICMP packet: read ip 0.0.0.0: raw-read ip4 0.0.0.0: use of closed network connection
Error reading ICMP packet: read ip 0.0.0.0: raw-read ip4 0.0.0.0: use of closed network connection

Comment: So `for idx, ip := range ips {` will run starting off goroutines; chances are it will exit before any responses are received. At that point `ip` will be set to the last IP and that is what you print. See [this](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview). However there is another problem; you will end up with multiple goroutines waiting on `replyChannel` so should not assume responses will be received in the expected order (even if there is no chan ordering issue, ping response time will vary so send order != receive order).

Comment: thanks @Brits. I changed to overcome the forloop issue:-  
        for idx, ip := range ips {  
                ipCopy := ip  
                idxCopy := idx  
                targetIP := net.ParseIP(ipCopy). 
now i get better display but incorrect results ...  

Received reply from 18.67.111.128 ...  reply id: 9933, seq: 0  
Received reply from 1.2.3.4 ...  reply id: 59711, seq: 16  
etc  
No response from 6.6.6.6  
No response from 203.219.106.90  
some ip's which aren't reachable are show as responding. I thought icmp would differentiate based on ID/seq even if out of order?

Comment: "...out of order" How? You have one goroutine receiving ICMP responses, parsing them and dumping them on a channel. There are a few bits of info you can use - the `net.Addr` returned by [`PacketConn.ReadFrom`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/icmp#PacketConn.ReadFrom) and the `Identifier` (`echoReply.ID` which you would need to match with the one you sent). Note that the address that the response is from will not always be the system you pinged... You may find [this package](https://github.com/prometheus-community/pro-bing) useful.